# How to get change events through Mylyn programatically?

Tags: java, eclipse, mylyn

For my project I want to access the data from as many bug- and work-item repositories as possible (for development in Eclipse). Therefore I use the Mylyn plugin because it already provides a framework for efficient use of multiple sources.

If I found out right, the tasks are saved under `.metadata\.mylyn\tasks.xml.zip\tasklist.xml` and `.metadata\.mylyn\tasks\<folder>\<id>.zip\data.xml`. But I don't know how to access the data and get changes...

- Is there a possibility to receive a notification if a task changes (e.g. if a work item status changes from CONFIRMED to SOLVED)?
- Is it somehow possible to subscribe to the Mylyn event which shows a little notification if something changes? Or is there something like an eventlogger or resource change listener?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mylyn has all of this data accessible by a variety of API's.  You can use the ITaskDataManager API (accessible via TasksUi.getTaskDataManager()) to get the full task data for a given task. You can listen for changes to when the task data is updated (e.g. there was a change to a task) using the ITaskDataManagerListener and attaching your listener to the TaskDataManager, then you can look at the task data to get what the values of the fields that you are interested in are. To see how the notification popup uses this, you can look at the TaskListNotifier.

Feel free to email mylyn-integrators@eclipse.org if you have more questions.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I will try these API's and send an email for further questions.